# How to load data from a datagrid view to a separate windows form on a button click event?

Tags: c#, mysql

My datagrid view consist with rows of data which are imported from a MySQL database. What I need to do is to load data of the selected row from the datagrid view to a separate form on a button click event.

[This is the screenshot of my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDw8p.jpg)

I have already implemented this by making the **Update Book Title** form text boxes modifiers to **Public** and writing this coding.

```
private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Update_Book_Title form = new Update_Book_Title();

    form.txt_booknumber.Text = this.datagrid_booktitles.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    form.txt_isbn.Text = this.datagrid_booktitles.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    form.txt_author.Text = this.datagrid_booktitles.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    form.txt_booktitle.Text = this.datagrid_booktitles.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    form.txt_publishedyear.Text = this.datagrid_booktitles.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    form.txt_publisher.Text = this.datagrid_booktitles.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    form.txt_category.Text = this.datagrid_booktitles.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    form.arrived_date.Text = this.datagrid_booktitles.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
    form.txt_price.Text = this.datagrid_booktitles.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
    form.txt_quantity.Text = this.datagrid_booktitles.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();

    form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    form.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    form.Show();
}
```

I know this is not the best solution for this, Are there any alternatives in doing this, So that I can load data from my datagrid view to Update Book Title windows form on Update button click event?

Answer (score 0):

Use property (POCO) class to assign the values from `DataGridView` and load them into entry form.